# How can we get Gravatar Hovercards on SO?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Recently, Automattic (the people behind the Gravatar service) [announced a new "hovercard" feature](http://blog.gravatar.com/2010/10/06/gravatar-hovercards-on-wordpress-com/) for gravatars.  When you hover your mouse for a moment over a gravatar, it rotates slightly, then pops up a javascript-powered profile of the current user.  This is an excellent way to tie Gravatar Profiles in to other sites, and it's already in use widely on WordPress.com.

What would it take to add this feature to SO and SO-related sites?  We already use gravatars, and it's fairly easy to include the script that adds hovercards by adding the following to a page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://s.gravatar.com/js/gprofiles.js?ver=e'></script>
```

Comment: This sounds like the feature on Meta Chat.

Comment: Oh, I'd say that that's a bad feature if it happens that everyone is automatically opt-ed in for that "howercard" thing (on gravatars end - not SO's end) - else I'd say it's cool.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be confusing. People already have profiles on the sites themselves so I don't see the point of adding emphasis to profiles on another site. It would be nice if SE sites had a similar feature for their own profiles, though.